# How to generate pdf's in laravel using codedge/laravel-fpdf?

Tags: php, laravel-5, fpdf

In my laravel application i used codedge/laravel-fpdf to generate pdf. I followed the below steps to install it.

1. composer require codedge/laravel-fpdf.
2. Added `Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class` and `'Fpdf' => Codedge\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class` in `config/app.php` file.

Then i tried to generate pdf from routes as below,

```
Route::get('mypdf', function () {
Fpdf::AddPage();
Fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
Fpdf::Output();
```

});

But i am getting below error,
[image: fatal error]

Any solution ? (My laravel version 5.0)

Comment: Please show Ur controller file

Comment: @ImAtWar which controller here i tried to generate pdf from routes file.

Comment: add in your controller
"Use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\FPDF;"
Please check Url -http://pdfdownload19.blogspot.in/2016/11/laravel-53-codedgelaravel-fpdf-class.html

Comment: Are you importing the nessicary files in ur routes? Dont know if it would work in Ur routes, its supposed to be used to pass `GET` and `POST` requests

Comment: @ImAtWar i tried use Fpdf; and use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\FPDF; in routes but no change. Same error

Comment: Cannyou try to clear cache? `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: "composer dump-autoload" for your Composer autoload classes

Comment: @ImAtWar just now i tried but same error.

Comment: @RahulPrajapati i tried dump-autoload still getting same error.

Comment: Maybe try a composer install? And update?

Comment: May I suggest where the source of the problem is?
src/Fpdf/fpdf.php file defines a class named FPDF and the service provider searches for the correct class name FPDF all uppercase. However, it seems the psr-4 autoloader expects file name to match class name in case-sensitive fashion:
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

I have this failing with laravel 4.2 project with same error of Class not found. Renaming fpdf.php to FPDF.php fixes the problem. Not sure why it works sometimes but it seems file name must be fixed...

Comment: @ImAtWar actually i took [link](https://packagist.org/packages/codedge/laravel-fpdf) this reference to install fpdf.

Comment: **Renaming fpdf.php to FPDF.php** correct file with difference on upper/lower case. As a class has to be start with Upper case , i just renamed filename as well, everything working perfectly.
cheers

Comment: [link](https://github.com/codedge/laravel-fpdf/issues/2)

Comment: @RahulPrajapati in my **vendor\codedge\laravel-fpdf\src** i had `fpdf.php` files each in **Fpdf,Facades,config** folders to which file i have to rename ?

Comment: src/Fpdf/fpdf.php because  file defines a class named FPDF and the service provider searches for the correct class name FPDF all uppercase. However, it seems the psr-4 autoloader expects file name to match class name in case-sensitive

Comment: @RahulPrajapati i renamed it and tried still same error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss publish command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

Answer (score 0):

use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf; 
include this file at top its start working